# converting date and/or time from character string..... how to solve this error

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i write this

```
ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(date,tblMR.MRIssuedDate)),'No') AS MN
```

Comment: Explain the error and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 3):

`ISNULL()` has to decide the type for its result -- and dates and strings are not compatible.  Actually, by the rules of SQL the string is converted to a date and not vice versa.

So, if the issue date is really a string, just do:

```
 COALESCE(MAX(tblMR.MRIssuedDate), 'No') as MN
```

If the date is really a date time or something like that, then convert it to a string:

```
 COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CONVERT(date, MAX(tblMR.MRIssuedDate))), 'No') as MN
```